# How to let my app show up as a gallery?

Tags: java, android, gallery, share, android-4.2-jelly-bean

there are apps out there which show up as a gallery when you want to add/share a picture (if you click on share -> gallery, you can choose between the native Android Gallery app and the custom gallery app).

I want to write such a gallery app myself. How do I manage my own app to show up as a gallery on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is, when a user wants to 'pick' an item, then your app should show up. For this, include these lines in your manifest, inside the  tag:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

You can further filter what kind of items the user can 'pick' from your app by specifying mimetype:

```
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
<data android:mimeType="video/*" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that code but it still does not do what I want. Here's an example: If you install the app "Smileys for Whatsapp" on google play, and then you want to attach a smiley in a whatsapp conversation - the "Smileys for Whatsapp" application can be chosen within Whatsapp if you click on "Gallery". This is exactly what I want - I want to show my app up on that place. Thanks

Comment: For this whatsapp might be providing some intent filter that you should use in your manifest. Check their forums or documentation if any.