# Android app appearing on gallery shares

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, gallery, share, whatsapp

I've been searching how to make an application appear in the Gallery share menu but I haven't find anything. There's a similar question here in SO but it hasn't been answered (link: [How to let my app show up as a gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433475/how-to-let-my-app-show-up-as-a-gallery)).

So, summing up:
I am trying to make a Whatsapp emoji application and I'd like to provide my users a direct access to the app via whatsapp, and the best way of doing it that I've seen is what other emoji apps in the market do, as you can see in the following image:

[image: App in gallery share]

I'm pretty sure it's achieved via intent-filters or something like that but I haven't found any solution.
Thank you in advance!